# percona replication change master

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm trying to set up replication between two MySQL servers. From the slave I log in as follows:

```
 mysql --host=10.32.8.187 --user=repl --password=********
```

My `CHANGE MASTER` statement:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO 
MASTER_HOST='10.32.8.187', 
MASTER_USER='repl', 
MASTER_PASSWORD='********', 
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysqld-bin.000006', 
MASTER_LOG_POS=632;
```

But Im getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

When I run show grants I get the following

```
Grants for repl@10.32.8.% 
GRANT RELOAD, PROCESS, SUPER, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'repl'@'10.32.8.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19'
```

So surely I already have the SUPER privilege?

(I'm running Percona-Server-55.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although restarting the servers worked, you may only have needed to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to reload the grants.

Answer (score 2):

So I flushed iptables and restarted the servers and hey presto. Sorry for time wasting